# Every User has the same profile picture (Firebase / Swift)

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-storage

Good Afternoon Community,

In my Swift App, every User has the same profile picture which is uploaded at Firebase Storage. How can I change it, so every User has his own unique profile picture?

How I upload the picture:

```
   @IBAction func UploadImage(_ sender: Any) {
        
        
        let picker = UIImagePickerController()
        
        picker.sourceType = .photoLibrary
        
        picker.delegate = self
        picker.allowsEditing = true
        present(picker, animated: true)
        
        
        
    }
    
    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
        picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        guard let image = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.editedImage] as? UIImage else {
            return
        }
        guard let imageData = image.pngData() else {
            return
        }
        
    
        
            storage.child("images/file.png").putData(imageData, metadata: nil, completion: { _, error in
            guard error == nil else {
                print("Failed to upload")
                return
            }
            
            
            
            
        })
        
        
    }

    
    func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
        picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    
    
}
```

How I download them:

```
func downloadImages() {
    
    let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference()
    
    
    
    
    // Reference to an image file in Firebase Storage
    let reference = storageRef.child("images/file.png")

    // UIImageView in your ViewController
    let imageView: UIImageView = self.imageView

    // Placeholder image
    let placeholderImage = UIImage(named: "placeholder.jpg")

    // Load the image using SDWebImage
    imageView.sd_setImage(with: reference, placeholderImage: placeholderImage)
        
        
   
}
```

Thanks for any Help!!! I didn't found this issue here...

EDIT:
Downloading the pictures for each user

```
 if Auth.auth() != nil {
        let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference()
        
        
        
        
        // Reference to an image file in Firebase Storage
        let reference = storageRef.child("images/"+Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid+".png")

        // UIImageView in your ViewController
        let imageView: UIImageView = self.imageView

        // Placeholder image
        let placeholderImage = UIImage(named: "placeholder.jpg")

        // Load the image using SDWebImage
        imageView.sd_setImage(with: reference, placeholderImage: placeholderImage)
            
            
       
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All your users are now writing the exact same file in Firestore Storage in:

```
storage.child("images/file.png").putData(imageData, metadata: nil, completion: { _, error in
```

To give every user a unique file, you'll want to include something that identifies the user in the file's path in Storage. Typically you'll use the UID of the user in Firebase Authentication for that.

So you'd [get the signed in user](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user) and then use their UID in the path:

```
if Auth.auth().currentUser != nil {
    storage.child("images/"+Auth.auth().currentUser.uid+"+.png").putData(imageData, metadata: nil, completion: { _, error in
        ...
}
```

On the reading side, you'll then want to [list the files](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/ios/list-files), and display them each individually.

Comment: ok if I upload a picture for each user account it is now working fine ;) I have currentUser forced (Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid) because Xcode is complaining. If I now want to download it it is not working as it should. I edited the post.

Comment: If you have a new problem after applying the solution in this answer, open a new question for the new problem please.

Comment: now I got it and I will pick your answer as SOLVED ;) I have every time to delete and new install the App if I want to see the changes. Is there a way to get this in time? Should I add a new topic for this?